# If duck-typing in Python, should you test isinstance?

Tags: python, equality, duck-typing

You have a Python class which needs an equals test. Python should use duck-typing but is it (better/more accurate) to include or exclude an isinstance test in the **eq** function? For example:

```
class Trout(object):
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return isinstance(other, Trout) and self.value == other.value
```

Comment: I think this is a legitimate use case for `isinstance`.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Using isinstance in `__eq__` methods is pretty common. The reason for this is that if the `__eq__` method fails, it can fallback on an `__eq__` method from another object. Most normal methods are called explicitly, but `__eq__` is called implicitly, so it requires look-before-you-leap more frequently.

EDIT (thanks for the reminder, Sven Marnach):

To make it fallback, you can return the NotImplemented singleton, as in this example:

```
class Trout(object):
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value

    def __eq__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, Trout):
            return self.value == other.value
        else:
            return NotImplemented
```

Suppose a `RainbowTrout` knows how to compare itself to a `Trout` or to another `RainbowTrout`, but a `Trout` only knows how to compare itself to a `Trout`. In this example, if you test `mytrout == myrainbowtrout`, Python will first call `mytrout.__eq__(myrainbowtrout)`, notice that it fails, and then call `myrainbowtrout.__eq__(mytrout)`, which succeeds.

Comment: While this answer is true, it doesn't explain how to implement `__eq__()` in a way that actually facilitates a fallback to the other object's `__eq__()`.

Answer (score 9):

Using `isintsance()` is usually fine in `__eq__()` methods.  You shouldn't return `False` immediately if the `isinstance()` check fails, though -- it is better to return `NotImplemented` to give `other.__eq__()`  a chance of being executed:

```
def __eq__(self, other):
    if isinstance(other, Trout):
        return self.x == other.x
    return NotImplemented
```

This will become particularly important in class hierarchies where more than one class defines `__eq__()`:

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x
    def __eq__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, A):
            return self.x == other.x
        return NotImplemented
class B(A):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        A.__init__(self, x)
        self.y = y
    def __eq__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, B):
            return self.x, self.y == other.x, other.y
        return NotImplemented
```

If you would return `False` immediately, as you did in your original code, you would lose symmetry between `A(3) == B(3, 4)` and `B(3, 4) == A(3)`.

Answer (score 5):

The "duck-typing" principle is that you don't care what `other` is, as long as it has a `value` attribute. So unless your attributes share names with conflicting semantics, I'd suggest doing it like this:

```
def __eq__(self, other):
    try:
        return self.value == other.value
    except AttributeError:
        return False # or whatever
```

(Alternately you could test whether `other` has a `value` attribute, but "it's easier to ask forgiveness than to get permission")

Comment: This might result in something very silly, like `Trout("rainbow") == Lorikeet("rainbow")`, even though hardly anyone would consider fish equal to birds.

Comment: @Token, in that case duck typing is not right for you. These would only come out equal if they both store "rainbow" in the attribute "value", by the way.

Comment: ... and you define their `__eq__` method as the OP wants, to only look at the `value` field. But yes, that's the duck typing principle. Love it or leave it.

Comment: A rather significant drawback of this approach though is that the try/except is *much* slower (about 60% when I did a test).  See https://gist.github.com/2950940  Arguably the try/except is more Pythonic, but I'd rather have fast non-pythonic code than slow pythonic code. :)

Comment: Python exceptions are designed to be very fast, but of course they won't be as fast as a simple type look-up. Unless you're using this for numeric processing, though, I'd be more worried about optimizing programmer productivity (read: extension-friendly design) than about shaving milliseconds.

Comment: Anyway the cost is incurred only when the `value` field is missing-- the rest of the time you should get a small speed-up from avoiding a test.